# Get woocommerce field values in external file

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Whenever a client places an order they receive an email. This email is generated in a file located at: `/woocommerce/emails/customer-processing-order.php`

I want to customize this email and get field values from the fields that the customer filled. For example I would like to add something like : Dear [first-name]. First name being a variable. How do I achieve this ?

The current email template looks like this:

```
<?php
/**
 * Customer processing order email
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/emails/customer-processing-order.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see         https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @author      WooThemes
 * @package     WooCommerce/Templates/Emails
 * @version     2.5.0
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}

/**
 * @hooked WC_Emails::email_header() Output the email header
 */


do_action( 'woocommerce_email_header', $email_heading, $email ); ?>

<p><?php _e( "Your order has been received and is now being processed. Your order details are shown below for your reference:", 'woocommerce' ); ?></p>

<?php

/**
 * @hooked WC_Emails::order_details() Shows the order details table.
 * @hooked WC_Structured_Data::generate_order_data() Generates structured data.
 * @hooked WC_Structured_Data::output_structured_data() Outputs structured data.
 * @since 2.5.0
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_email_order_details', $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email );

/**
 * @hooked WC_Emails::order_meta() Shows order meta data.
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_email_order_meta', $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email );

/**
 * @hooked WC_Emails::customer_details() Shows customer details
 * @hooked WC_Emails::email_address() Shows email address
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_email_customer_details', $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email );

/**
 * @hooked WC_Emails::email_footer() Output the email footer
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_email_footer', $email );
```

Comment: You need to add a custom field to checkout and get that value in email

Answer (score 0):

I had expected I would need to add some kind of filter or hook in order to get the values the customers fills in. Apparently this is not the case. I can just get the values as follow without having modify the template:

```
$_POST['fieldname'];
```